# x cannot be resolved as a variable

Tags: java, arrays, loops

What is wrong with this loop?

```
int index = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < winDate.length;x++);
{
    if(userDate == winDate[x])
    {
        index = x;
        break;
    }
}
```

I've used x several times before in comparing values.

Comment: because you have closed for loop typo error

Answer (score 6):

You have got a ";" behind the loop!
In fact this loop does nothing instead of counting.
The part below the loop is getting to initialized statically.

```
int index = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < winDate.length;x++)-->;<---
{
    if(userDate == winDate[x])
    {
        index = x;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But userDate is a 1D array and winDate is actually a 2D array. Is that comparision okay?

Comment: @user3457598 in that case no

Comment: @user3457598 No. Those references will never be `==`.

Comment: @user3457598 i suggest to look up comparisons between arrays in java